# JSON::ParserError 757 Unexpected token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, steam

A little background on what I'm working on. I'm trying to create an app to spice up my coding portfolio but I can't get this app to work with me. I followed a guide for part of it, specifically integrating Steam OpenID/Omniuath with Ruby on Rails since it uses POST with no CSRF token....yadda yadda yadda. Anyhoo, what I'm trying to get this to do so far is upon logging in through steam, just for this moment, a list of the players owned games will display. However it's not working with me. My code is below for my controller.

```
    class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :auth_callback
  def index
    @gameslibrary = []
    if session.key? :current_user
    url = URI.parse("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=#{ENV['STEAM_WEB_API_KEY']}&account_id=#{session[:current_user][:uid]}")
    res = Net::HTTP::get(url)
    @gameslibrary = JSON.parse(res)['game_count']['app_id']['name']['playtime_forever'] || []
  end
end
  def auth_callback
      auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
      session[:current_user] = { :nickname => auth.info['nickname'],
                                            :image => auth.info['image'],
                                            :uid => auth.uid }
      redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

And here is my view code

```
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<%= link_to image_tag("http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_large_noborder.png"), '/auth/steam' %>
<% if session.key? :current_user %>
<h3>Current User:</h3>
<%= image_tag session[:current_user][:image] %>
<p><%= session[:current_user][:nickname] %></p>
<p><%= session[:current_user][:uid] %> </p>
<% end %>
<ul>
  <% @gameslibrary.each do |game| %>
  <li><%= puts game %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

my JSON parse comes back with the following

```
757: unexpected token at '<html> <head> <title>500 Internal Server Error</title> </head> <body> <h1>Internal Server Error</h1> </body> </html>'
```

Now the Steam Web API does support JSON output. And those items after the JSON parse are actual names of arrays/items in arrays. What am I doing wrong here? And for even more help how would I convert the the JSON parse data from an array into a hash? (or is that automatic?) I'm new to most of this and this is my first app I've done mostly on my own. I'm using GetOwnedGamesv0001 from the Steam Web API if anyone wants to look at it.

Comment: Please post the output of `Net::HTTP::get(url)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for sure is the response, this is an invalid JSON, what you can do first of all move this code to model then check what response code you get from the url you try to send the request if it different then 200 don't try JSON.parse the response because you will get the error you get now.

do something like:

```
url =      URI.parse("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=#{ENV['STEAM_WEB_API_KEY']}&account_id=#{session[:current_user][:uid]}")

if Net::HTTP.get_response(url).kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess
  @gameslibrary = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP::get(url))['game_count']['app_id']['name']['playtime_forever'] || []
else
  ... raise or log or something ...
end
```